# Can we use multiple libraries in angular(2/4/5/6) because it supports TreeShaking ? Without hitting the performance and build size

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6

I have gone through this article : https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/6a678s/primeng_vs_material2/
In the comment they mentioned we can use **Prime Ng** and **Angular material**
together in app. In **PrimeNg** components are standalone modules mostly so you can add only the ones you need and same is true for **Angular material** after couple of updates.

My question is... Can we use multiple number of libraries as many as we want with Angular app Like: PrimeNg, Angular material, Fuse and many more. Without affecting the performance or size of the build, because Tree shaking will take care of it. 
Basically I want to use Material only for designing layout and some look and feel that.

Also, Does angular(5/6) supports 100% tree shaking or still we need to use Rollup.js ? Gone through multiple article but not sure yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build an Angular app with production flag, every component, service, directive or pipe is referenced at least once (in `@NgModule` annotations). At the end of the AOT compilation, the compiler removes these annotations and after that it also removes unreferenced things.

[Source](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2017/07/27/the-angular-bundle-optimizer-under-the-hoods.aspx)

That said, every Angular Material component is a module, which gives you fine grained import of the library.

I don't know PrimeNg, but from what I quickly searched and as you already know it seems to have one module per component too.

Using both libraries should not affect bundle size nor performance, but you should be aware that the "look and feel" differs from UI library to UI library

Comment: It's pretty much clear now...it means we can add as many as libraries we want if they have standalone module, rest tree shaking will take care of :) , but anyway that is not right way to include multiple libraries.
So angular supports full treeshaking or do we really need rollup.js?

Comment: I don't fully get what you're asking. rollup.js is a bundler. Angular comes with its CLI which uses webpack as a bundler and does tree-shaking, uglify, etc... You should use the Angular CLI unless you want to do very specific things in your build pipeline

Comment: If you see this link https://kbtechbook.wordpress.com/2017/06/10/ahead-of-time-compilation-and-tree-shaking-for-angular-2-application-using-angularcli-and-rollup-js/ might you will understand about rollup.js and what I am trying to say. 
and here the first comment thread will give you more clearity
https://blog.rangle.io/optimize-your-angular2-application-with-tree-shaking/

Comment: Ok I see, but the first article is one year old, the 2nd is even older. Angular 5 and 6 focused mainly on performance and bundle size. IMHO it is overkill to perform a custom build pipeline just in order to reduce the bundle size. I'd like to see a benchmark between Angular 6 CLI and this kind of technique