# Unused components of third party libraries (PrimeNG, ngx-bootstrap, etc)

Tags: javascript, components, bundle, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

I'm creating a project on Angular 6 and using ngx-bootstrap as my components library.

I'm not using all the components that the library offer just a few of them. So my question is, At the moment to pass to production on my Angular application, the unused components from ngx-bootstrap will or will not be added on the final build bundle? if does, this will hit on the bundle size or performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build an Angular app with production flag, every component, service, directive or pipe is referenced at least once (in @NgModule annotations). At the end of the AOT compilation, the compiler removes these annotations and after that it also removes unreferenced things.

If your library uses module based design then definitely it wont affect your bundle size.
As mentioned at ngx-bootstrap website. 
**We put much effort making ngx-bootstrap modular.**
So it should not affect your performance and bundle size.
For more detail check this:
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043663/can-we-use-multiple-libraries-in-angular2-4-5-6-because-it-supports-treeshakin)